# How can I see an overview of production or consumption?

Tags: anno-2070

I'd like to see an overview of my production and consumption rates.

By knowing what the current economy is, it would help in things like deciding whether to have a mine produce iron or coal.

How can I see such data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't inside the game. However, since the consumption and production rates are fixed to the number and type of inhabitants, there are calculator online that help you with that and can tell you exactly what are your consumption rates by number and type of residents, or you can put the number of houses you have/want and get the eventual consumption of your population.

To see what different calculator are available go to the [calculators page](http://anno2070.wikia.com/wiki/Calculators) on the Anno 2070 wiki.

Comment: Oh wow, that nuts. Thanks for the information, but this is definitely not my style of play. Too bad there's not a live heads up to see what's going on with supply and demand.